# Does GIT ensure commit timestamp order?

Tags: git

Let's say 2 computers are pushing to the same git repo, computer A has the current date time and computer B has the datetime set to 1 year earlier.

Say computer A pushed some commits, and computer B check them out and add some more commits based on the same branch and push.

```
*A (dated 2020-07-28 by computer A push) ----> *B (dated 2019-07-28 by computer B)
```

What will happen? Does git makes sure the child commits' timestamp have to be later than the parent commits?

Comment: Git doesn't link or sort commit by dates.

Comment: `git commit --date=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. One way you’ll often find out-of-order timestamps compared to the commit graph is when rebasing onto an updated upstream is part of your workflow.

Comment: No. The timestamp is recorded as is. It can be easily forged, for example by the environmental variables `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, like `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='1997-01-01 12:00:00 -0800' GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='2030-01-01 12:00:00 +0800' git commit --allow-empty -m"I am a false commit."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no constraint on timestamps in commits.

A commit stores explicitly the id of its parent(s), and git allows a commit to have a timestamp smaller than one of its parents'

A commit actually has 2 timestamps :

- a creation date, called "author date"
- a modification date, called "committer date"

Several features of git allow you to rewrite the repo's history (`git rebase`, `git cherry-pick`, `git commit --amend`, `git filter-branch` ...), and as a result, all interleavings of timestamps are possible.

---

To give an illustrative example :

If you run `git commit`, and 1 hour later you run `git commit --amend` : the "author date" will be 1 hour ago, the "committer date" will be now.
Similarly, with `git cherry-pick othercommit`, or `git rebase` (which is roughly like running `git cherry-pick` in a loop) : the resulting "author date" will be the author date of the original commit, the "committer date" will be now.

---

When working from a single machine, you will most probably see a chronological order in the modification dates (note that it is not *enforced* though, if you set your system clock to "yesterday" git will happily indulge) ; when working accross several machines, git does not handle time shifts between the systems' clocks.

---

You can view the two timestamps with several commands :

- for a single commit :

  ```
  # will display timestamps rendered in human format :
  git show -s --format=fuller <branch or commit id>   # default is head

  # will display raw unix timestamps as stored in the commit :
  git cat-file -p <branch or commit id>
  git cat-file -p HEAD
  ```
- for each commit in a branch :

  ```
  git log --format=fuller
  git log --format=fuller branch1 branch2 ...
  ```
- with rendering options of `git log` or `git for-each-ref` : see the `--format` paragraph for each of these commands

Most GUI frontends to git (e.g : gitk, git-kraken, git-extensions, sourcetree ...) will also display the two timestamps in a commit's details.

Comment: Could you please make the `committer date` more clear?

Comment: If you `git commit`, and 1 hour later you `git commit --amend` : the "author date" will be 1 hour ago, the "committer date" will be now. Similar with `git cherry-pick othercommit` : the resulting "author date" will be the author date of the original commit, the "committer date" will be now.